# Error while unzip file in parallel

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter, gunzip

We have few Informatica session where we are using below command to read zip files

```
gunzip -c all_data.csv.gz
```

we are asked (by client) to read files as gz only and we can not unzip and save file. 
Few of our Informatica session reads zip files directly but while reading same files session sometimes failes with error

```
Error reading from file [gunzip -c all_data.csv.gz
].  Operating system error message [Invalid argument].
```

If we restart the session it runs successfully
can anyone please help on this.
Thanks
in advance

Comment: What happens after reading the file in a session? How is the file deleted?

Comment: when all the workflow is completed we just move the file to a archive folder.

Comment: Are you sure that **all** sessions have read the file before it is moved to the archive folder?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure about this , even if you restart failed session it runs successfully.

Comment: After looking again on the error, I guess that it might be that the file name is sometimes includes the newline symbol like this `all_data.csv.gz\n`. Please check it

Comment: no we have checked this , there is no \n character in session.

Comment: Any other unprintable symbol?